# Julia: Convert Float64 to Date and to DateTime

Tags: julia

In Julia I have a float like `2018.003828474404`. This Float should be interpretted to represent the `DateTime(2018,1,2,9,53,1)`. Here the `.003828474404` component of the float represents the fraction of the year elapsed since the start of 2018.

1. How do I convert from the `Float64` to a `DateTime`.
2. How do I convert from the `Float64` to a `Date`. This will lose precision and risks an `InexactError()` but for my purposes the nearest day is fine.

Comment: What does the `0.003828...` represent? My first guess was that it indicated proportion of year elapsed, but that doesn't make sense since `0.003828 * 365 = 1.397...` which would imply `DateTime(2018,1,2,9,53)` (roughly), whereas you said the float represented `DateTime(2018,1,1,12,30,1)`.

Comment: @ColinTBowers you are right and that is the correct interpretation. I must have a bug in the function (not included above) I used to convert from DateTime to float. I have corrected it now in the question.

Comment: How did you end up with these? Why not just use unix timestamps? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: I want to be able to use this in financial calculations and a float for years seems more intuitive in this case. Like $e^{r(2018.5-2016)}$ gives returns from interest rate $r$ from 2016 to halfway through 2018. I could use Unix integers I guess but then I have to keep converting interest rates or time (measured in  milliseconds) so both are consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it seems like a fixed quantity with respect to a year, the `0.003828...` value after `2018` represents a fraction of the *specific* year between 2018 and 2019, since all years vary slightly in length (e.g. leap years). `Dates` takes this fact seriously.

We can define the following function `partial_year` to calculate the result with a specified precision (defaulting to `Nanosecond`, the most specific provided by `Dates`).

```
using Dates

function partial_year(period::Type{<:Period}, float::AbstractFloat)
    _year, Δ = divrem(float, 1)
    year_start = DateTime(_year)
    year = period((year_start + Year(1)) - year_start)
    partial = period(round(Dates.value(year) * Δ))
    year_start + partial
end
partial_year(float::AbstractFloat) = partial_year(Nanosecond, float)
```

First, we split out the starting year from the remaining fraction of the year. We use `Dates` handling of time periods to calculate the exact length of the specified year, converting it to type `period` for our desired precision. We multiply this `year` value by the fraction of the year, round the result (because fractional `Period`s aren't allowed), and convert it back to a `period`. Finally, we add this `partial` year to the `year_start`.

As expected, we can use this on your example, with various precisions:

```
julia> partial_year(2018.003828474404)
2018-01-02T09:32:14.768

julia> partial_year(Minute, 2018.003828474404)
2018-01-02T09:32:00
```